# Call jQuery function in Android's WebView from Java?

Tags: jquery, android, android-webview

I am trying to call javascript function which is defined in html
like

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:hoge()");
```

I can call non-jQuery function, but I can't call the function which I defined inside the '$(document).ready(function(){})(jQuery);', like bellow.

```
<script>
//I can call this function by webview.loadUrl("javascript:something()");
function something(){
    //do something
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //but I can't call this function by webview.loadUrl("javascript:hoge()");
    function hoge(){
        //do something.
    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Is there a way to call hoge() from Java like ordinary javascript function?

I found that I can use jQuery Selector even if the function is not inside  '$(document).ready(function(){})(jQuery);', but I also find that with that workaround, I can't use additional jQuery library.

belllow is the actual code.

https://github.com/YoshimuraSei/AndrOutliner/tree/master/Outliner

and this is html file
https://github.com/YoshimuraSei/AndrOutliner/blob/master/Outliner/assets/www/treeview.html

and this is java code which I am trying to call javascript function.
https://github.com/YoshimuraSei/AndrOutliner/blob/master/Outliner/src/com/yslibrary/android/outliner/TreeViewFragment.java

on line 100, I am trying to call javascript function'test1()'(see line34 of the html file), and it can be called since currently it is not inside '$(document).ready(function(){})(jQuery);', but I can't call extra jQuery library method 'nestedSortable()' from test1().

How can I solve this?

**Edit:**
Or is this just a timing of loading jQuery library and plugins?
I got these error after load html to webview.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined--From line 7 of file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.ui.mouse.touch.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortable' of undefined--From line 15 of file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.ui.nestedSortable.js
```

'mouse' and 'sortable' are properties of jquery.ui, which should be loaded before these 2 files are loaded, so I assume that Load order is little bit strange.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is pass a query string parameter when you call the webview (eg. method=hoge).

Then in your javascript you can check the existance of the param and run the `hoge()` method accordingly

Not sure if your interested, but you can also call your android java code from javascript using the android javascript interface, see http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. you mean, I have to reload html each time when I want to use method, right?

Comment: problem solved. the problem was a typo. and thank you for the info about android javascript interface. I found the way to pass javascript function return value to Java code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working as a JavaScript engineer. From this experience, now I can see what was wrong.
It's a scope & timing related issue.
Functions inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});` cannot be called from outside, since they are not global. if you want to call them from outside, you have to make it global. And you have to wait until javascript is fully loaded and ready to be used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // make it global function
    window.foo = function(){
        //do something.
    }

    // call java method that notifies java that js is ready to use.
    // (you should implement JavascriptInterface class & method)
    window.JsInterface.jsReady();
})(jQuery);
```

1. you have to expose functions to *Global*.
2. you have to wait until javascript is ready.

Comment: That explains a lot. I noticed that if I also put the function inside the main HTML page (the one first loaded by loadUrl()), then the second loadUrl() javascript call could find the function. However if I moved the function into a .js file, it stopped working.

Comment: @MichaelR.Hines not tested, but this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17041561/855599

Answer (score 0):

well, you can always call a javascript function using loadUrl methode of your webview;

```
myWebView.loadUrl("Javascript: alert('test');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your html file a jquery function and named for example show_main_pop :

```
function show_main_pop(){
  $('#r_and_h').fadeIn(500);
}
```

and in android studio call this function like that:

```
webframe.loadUrl("javascript: show_main_pop();")
```