# Call jQuery Function in Android WebView from Java using Local HTML

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to do something very similar to this post: [Call jQuery function in Android's WebView from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893964/call-jquery-function-in-androids-webview-from-java)

The only difference is my HTML file is local, so I'm accessing it via `file:///` in `loadURL`. Due to a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) in Android, I can't use URL parameters with file links.

So, how can I call a function that uses jQuery from Java in an Android app?