# Call jQuery function from Android by using WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I know that how to call a Javascript function from Android's webview. To call javascript function I've to use the following syntax.

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:my_javascript_func();");
```

But if I try to call a jquery function defined in $(document).ready(function(){}); area then it through "Uncaught ReferenceErro: my_jquery_func is not defined at null:1"

Where my_jquery_func() is the name of my jquery function.

I've searched enough but could not get any example of calling jQuery function from Android by using webview.

I can see a similar post here: [Call jQuery function in Android's WebView from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893964/call-jquery-function-in-androids-webview-from-java/21620766#21620766)

but it couldn't help me.

Thanks,

Comment: I found the answer. Almost the same problems has been described in the following link but since there were no exact answer that's why I posted this question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893964/call-jquery-function-in-androids-webview-from-java/21620766#21620766

The poster of that question(yshrsmz) has solved it and gave a detail of the solution upon my request. I think that link would be helpful. Thanks -Mushfique